# How can I find the difference between two plots with a dimensional mismatch?

Tags: matlab

I have a question that I don't know if there is a solution off the bat.

Here it goes,

I have two data sets, plotted on the same figure. I need to find their difference, simple so far...
the problem arises in the fact that say matrix `A` has 1000 data points while the second (matrix `B`) has 580 data points. How will I be able to find the difference between the two graphs since there is a dimensional miss match between the two figures.

One way that I thought of is artificially inflating matrix B to 1000 data points, but the trend of the plot will remain the same. Would this be possible? and if yes how?

for example:

```
A=[1 45 33 4 1009 ];
B=[1 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 1010];

Ya=A.*20+4;
Yb=B./10+3;

C=abs(B - A)

plot(A,Ya,'r',B,Yb)
xlim([-100 1000])
grid on
hold on
plot(length(B),C)
```

Comment: You have to inflate matrix B. Something like
B_in = zeros(size(A));

Than you have get the index of B in A. Where the point 567 in B is correspondent in A or in other words the X point of B
Then
B_in(indexCorrec) = B;
Then
diffe = diff([A,B_in]);

This is the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to resample the 580 element vector to 1000 samples. Use matlab `resample` (requires the Signal Processing Toolbox, I believe) for this:

```
x = randn(580,1);
y = randn(1000,1);

xr = resample(x, 50,29); # 50/29 = 1000/580 is the resampling ratio
```

You should then be able to compare the two data vectors.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I can think of:

**1- Matching the size:**

- Generating more data for the matrix with lower number of elements (using interpolation, etc.)
- Removing some data from the matrix with higher number of elements (i.e. outlier removal)

**2- Comparing the matrices with their properties.**

For instance, you can calculate the mean and the covariance of a matrix and compare it to the other matrix. The other options include, `cov` , `mean` , `median` , `std`,  var , `xcorr` , `xcov`.